# Preciso me conectar a um servidor socket externo através de URL

Tags: php, socket, websocket, fsockopen

Antes de mais nada, sei que existem milhares de tutoriais ensinando *sockets* internet afora. Porém, não encontrei nada especificadamente para a minha dificuldade, por isso me recorri ao **SO**.

Preciso criar um serviço *socket* em PHP para se conectar como cliente à um **servidor *socket* externo** e ficar escutando-o. O problema é que esse *host* externo é uma url com parâmetros e não um IP. Os métodos conhecidos no PHP como `socket_create()` só permitem receber um HOST (IP) e não uma URL.

O outro método conhecido `stream_socket_server()` permite conexão com URL, porém eu não consegui permanecer "escutando" o servidor com ele. Todos os tutoriais que encontrei também não ficam escutando, executa apenas um script e fecha a conexão.

Enfim, preciso de uma ajuda para abrir uma conexão *socket* com uma URL como cliente e ficar escutando-a.

```php
echo "Socket started...\n";

$server = 'ssl://sockserver.com/moreurl/params?56298';
$host = "sockserver.com";
$port = 80;
set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_connect($socket, $server, $port);
socket_bind($socket, $host);
socket_listen($socket);

while (true) {
  $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024);
  if($result){
    echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
  }
}

socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema usando a biblioteca [ratchetphp/Pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl) no GitHub. Essa biblioteca permite conexão PHP como cliente em um WSS.